# The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: azure, entity-framework-migrations

When I enter this command: 'Enable-Migrations' in Package Manager Console I get this error:

"The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a p
ath was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:18
+ Enable-Migrations <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-Migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"

I am using VS2010 with EF 4.0 and I was just doing really simple test project for deploying web site with windows azure,but for some reason I can not enable migrations.

Anyone has any idea?
Thanks

Comment: If it helps someone: I was suppose to install EF 4.3 so i can enable migrations.

Answer (score 13):

Try to restart Visual Studio. It helped in my case.

Answer (score 3):

First thing you need VS2010 Professional SP1.

After that please reinstall application package with commmand **Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease** and it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the latest EntityFramework and the 'Enable-Migrations' command is still showing the error reinstall/upgrade NuGet, see documentation: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a **solution opened**. I got this error because I tried to run it without any solution opened. When I opened a solution it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I was working on existing code-base which already had Entity Framework 5.x was installed. Some of the solutions suggested to upgrade to latest version and run but, installing the newest version remove `System.Data.Entity`. Adding the reference again caused errors in my old code which was using deprecated APIs.

The solution is run as administrator *if you've already installed the framework in your solution*

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and was using an old version of NuGet, what worked for me was updating NuGet via the extensions interface.

Answer (score -1):

"Install-Package EntityFramework" will work just as well