# The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized mvc code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I'm trying to run for the first time in my new mvc 4 application
    PM> Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations

I'm geting:

```
Enable-Migrations : The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations
```

What am I missing? I have installed e.f 5.

Comment: Have you installed entity framework? Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/11202718/1341477 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10411529/1341477 and http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2649

Comment: Sorry just edited my question, i meant e.f 5 not mvc 5!! So yes in answer to your question...

Comment: Are you want database migration?

Comment: I am yes. However I just removed my e.f reference and readded and it is now working... strange!

Comment: do you not agree with me,@Simon? :))

Comment: @Simon why did you accept his answer it is not correct?

Comment: @Dave OK have amended.

Answer (score 14):

Try typing in Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease
```

and then Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: restarting did the thrick!

Answer (score 1):

First "Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease" and then Restarting Visual Studio as a Administrator worked for me together.

[Refer this]  :  [Package Manager Console Enable-Migrations CommandNotFoundException only in a specific VS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411529/package-manager-console-enable-migrations-commandnotfoundexception-only-in-a-spe)

Answer (score 0):

I had the framework installed (5.x) and retried running the same commands after running in admin mode. This has resolved the issue -- quite strange though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you don't have any square brackets "[" in your path directory of the project. Apparently VS 2013 is not happy with project folders named with square brackets.